# Update all URL with a new domain in MongoDb Database

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongo-shell

I have a MongoDb database with multiple collections

Many collections have fields (with different names like; url, photo, baseImage, collection) that has a domain.

Problem Statement: I have to change the domain say from **DomainA.com** to **DomainB.com**

Is it possible to do it in one GO?

The collection may have a field or a Sub-Field and even Array...

Any help how to achieve this in a clean simple way is most invited.

Using Mongo-shell would be most preferred...

Thanks, in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using db.COLLECTION.updateMany(filter, update, options)

An example of your use case:

db.COLLECTION.updateMany({}, {$set: {domain: "domainB.com"}})

reference: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/